# How to use createDailyTimeSeriesEngine in different trading time periods?

Tags: time-series, dolphindb

First of all, I think that createDailyTimeSeriesEngine is very simple and effective.

The ticks of different exchanges are saved in the same ticks flow table. Different exchanges have different trading hours.

How should I aggregate the ticks, and how to use createDailyTimeSeriesEngine?

Answer (score 0):

What is your aggregation frequency? If the aggregation frequency is not so high, (which means that your result of the filter will not be too large, ) setting the maximum time range may meet your demand.
Or you can set up a filter by each Exchange, using “setStreamTableFilterColumn”, and create a subscription and calculation engine for each exchange with different trading hours.